# Unable to add sitemap.xml file and route in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, routes, sitemap

I am trying to add sitemap.xml file for an laravel website. I am using laravel version 9. I tried to search on google and youtube but not able to find any solution.

I have created a sitemap.xml file and I have moved sitemap.xml file to the public directory and I have added the route in the routes folder/directory like this to the file web.php where other routes are defined:

```
Route::get("sitemap.xml" , function () {
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('sitemap.xml');
 });
```

I have also tried to added the following code to the routes folder/directory like this :

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml',function() {
return response()->view('sitemap')
->header('Content-Type', 'xml');
});
```

Now open the xml file through url: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml, I get 500
SERVER ERROR.

Comment: I would directly put the file inside the `public` folder and that's it... no need to create a route or anything crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot link to a file, with a view method call. Put the file in the storage folder, and then use the file call to actually serve the file.

```
return response()->file('sitemap.xml');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate dynamically your sitemap and handle it from a blade view, you could make it like that:

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml', [SiteMapController::class, 'sitemap'])->name('sitemap');
```

Then in the SitemapController do the dynamic stuff and return the blade view:

```
$models = Model::all();
return response()->view('sitemap', compact('models'))->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

And the sitemap.blade.php in the views folder:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    @foreach ($models as $model)
    <url>
        <loc>{{ route('models.show', $model) }}</loc>
    </url>
    @endforeach
</urlset>
```